# How to Register inherited class and interface via autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I've got a scenario that forces me to derive some service classes from base services and some data access classes and interfaces as well. 
these are my base unit of work class and interface and DAL registery:

```
 public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
  {
  }

  public class UnitOfWork: IUnitOfWork
  {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }   
  }


public class DalRegistery : IRegistery
{ 
        public void Register(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>()
                .As<IUnitOfWork>()
                .As<DbContext>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }

}
```

and this is my derive class and interface from above base types:

```
 public interface IChildUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork 
  {
  }

 internal class ChildUnitOfWork : UnitOfWork, IChildUnitOfWork 
 {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }   
 }
```

now I'm trying to register childUnitOfwork rather than registering UnitOfwork (base unit of work) and this is the piece of code I've written:

```
public class ChildDalRegistery : IRegistery
{
   public void Register(ContainerBuilder builder)
   {
       builder.RegisterType<ChildUnitOfWork>().As<IChildUnitOfWork>().As<DbContext>.InstancePerLifetimeScope();
   }
}
```

but it doesn't even calls my ChildDalRegistery even application starting. is there any way in Autofac to register derived members??

Note: IRegistery is a custom interface that registers my classes in application start.

Comment: Can you show the code in application start? how you you using `DalRegistery` or `ChildDalRegistery`? Do your classes depend on `IUnitOfWork` or `IChildUnitOfWork`? If they depend on `IUnitOfWork` then you need to map `IUnitOfWork` to `ChildDalRegistery`.

Comment: All of my classes derived from IRegistery are collected in app start, what I want to register is both of UnitOfwork and ChildUnitOfWork in their own layer(as I mentioned childUnitOfwork is the child of UnitOfWork)